# WARNING in c called " 's1' and 's2' is used uninitialized in this function"

Tags: c, warnings

cant solve the warning in c called s1 s2 is used uninitialized this function

```
int main()
{
    char *s1, *s2;
    printf("Please enter string s1 and then s2:\n");
    scanf("%s %s", s1, s2);
    printf("%s %s", *s1, *s2);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate for `s1` and `s2`:

```
// do not forget to include the library <stdlib.h> for malloc function
s1 = malloc(20); // string length of s1 ups to 19;
if(!s1) {return -1;}
s2 = malloc(20) // // string length of s2 ups to 19 also;
if(!s2) {return -1;}
```

The in `scanf` function, should change to ([Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)):

```
scanf("%19s %19s", s1, s2); // or using fgets
```

Or you can use the array of character instead of using pointer:

```
char s1[20], s2[20];
// Or you can define a maximum length MAX_LEN, then using:
// char s1[MAX_LEN], s2[MAX_LEN];
```

Comment: Thanks,  I made it work with adding *s1=NULL, it turned that a pointer should be initialized in this situation

Comment: @AhmadIstaitih you are welcome.